# How to fix "invalid use of non-static member function" in a library importing another library

Tags: c++, oop, object, arduino, static-linking

I'm writing a library for arduino which at a certain point must call a function after a fixed delay without using the delay function.

Since standard c++ libraries are not included, I have to use arduino libraries, and I opted for FlexiTimer2 which is useful to run a function every X time units (this is just an introduction, the problem is not arduino related but c++ related).

**.h file**

```
#ifndef StepperDriverController_h
#define StepperDriverController_h

#include <stdlib.h>
#if ARDUINO >= 100
#include <Arduino.h>
#else
#include <WProgram.h>
#include <wiring.h>
#endif

class StepperDriverController
{
    public:
        StepperDriverController(unsigned char step, unsigned char direction);

        void setPulseWidth(unsigned short width);
        // other methods

    protected:
        void stepPinDown();
        void step(bool blocking = true);

    private:
        unsigned char _pins[2];
        // some attributes
};
#endif
```

**.cpp file**

```
#include "StepperDriverController.h"
#include <Thread.h>

void StepperDriverController::stepPinDown()
{
    digitalWrite(_pins[0], LOW);
    FlexiTimer2::stop();
}

void StepperDriverController::setPulseWidth(unsigned short width)
{
    _pulseWidth = width;
    FlexiTimer2::set(width, 1/1000000, stepPinDown);
}

void StepperDriverController::step()
{
    digitalWrite(_pins[1], _direction ? HIGH : LOW);

    digitalWrite(_pins[0], HIGH);
    FlexiTimer2::start();
}
```

I get **invalid use of non-static member function** on code *FlexiTimer2::set(width, 1/1000000, stepPinDown);* and **'_pins' was not declared in this scope** on *digitalWrite(_pins[0], LOW);*

I've read many questions related to this error but couldn't find a way to solve it anyway

**EDIT**

FlexiTimer should not be instantiated, but used as I did, as shown in an official library [example](https://codebender.cc/example/FlexiTimer2/FlashLed#FlashLed.ino)

Comment: You probably want to have an instance of `FlexiTimer2` as a class member variable of `StepperDriverController`. Also add the scope `StepperDriverController::`before your function definitions.`

Comment: I'd recommend you should read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) about c++ basics.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ actually if I had not a library but for example a main function, it would work because FlexiTimer is not a class but a namespace and it works exactly like that. Have a look at this: https://codebender.cc/example/FlexiTimer2/FlashLed#FlashLed.ino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FlexiTimer2::set()` overload you are trying to use is declared like this:

```
namespace FlexiTimer2 {
    // ...
    void set(unsigned long units, double resolution, void (*f)());
}
```

The third argument is `void (*f)()`. That's a function pointer to a *free function* returning void and taking no arguments. However, you are passing a *member function*. This can't work.

Then you attempted to change `stepPinDown()` from a member function into a free function. This won't work either, since making it a free function prevents it from accessing the members of `StepperDriverController`.

What you can do instead is pass a lambda that you force to be compatible with a free function (using the `+` syntax) like this:

```
FlexiTimer2::set(width, 1/1000000, +[]{ /* your code here */ });
```

Now the problem is how to get access to a `StepperDriverController` instance and call `stepPinDown()` on it. Normally with lambdas, you would simply do a lambda capture of the instance:

```
[&obj]{ obj.stepPinDown(); }
```

However, such a lambda can not be passed to a function that expects a function pointer. The `+` notation in `+[]{ /* your code here */ }` is just there to make it clear that the lambda **must not** capture anything. You can omit the `+` if you don't do a capture; it's purely there as a means of having self-documenting and clearer code.

So since you are not allowed to do a lambda capture, and I do not know the exact internals of your code, it's not clear how to best call `stepPinDown()` inside the lambda. But it seems that `StepperDriverController` is a singleton object, meaning there's only ever one instance of it. So you could have a global pointer to that instance and use that in the lambda:

```
FlexiTimer2::set(width, 1/1000000, +[]{ globalInstance->stepPinDown(); });
```

I can't tell you what the proper solution is in your case, but this is the gist of it.

There's also an issue that's unrelated to any of this, but it's worth pointing out:

```
1/1000000
```

This does not do what you think it does. This is integer division and the result will be 0. You need:

```
1.0/1000000.0
```

In order to get 0.000001 as the result.

Comment: Okay sorry, it was a typo of mine because I had tried many codes before actually posting here. In fact the error is still **invalid use of non-static member function** at *'void StepperDriverController::setPulseWidth(short unsigned int)'*

Comment: @Frank OK, now I understand the issue. Answer updated.

Comment: Ooh I like the `+`. Not necessary at all but presumably leads to better diagnostics if you forget not to capture anything?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Kind of. If you omit the `+` and then do a capture, the error message you get will be about the lambda not being convertable to a function pointer. With the `+`, it will be about the lambda itself. It's not really better though. Both are confusing if you don't know what's going on. But since a `+` forces the lambda to be generated as a free function and thus prevents captures, it kind of seems more "correct" to me.

Comment: @Nikos I _might_ start doing it :)

Comment: (I would suggest clarifying this a little in your answer, though, because at the moment it kind of reads like the `+` is necessary for the conversion to a fptr)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yep. Added a note about it.

Comment: Nice one. Take care!

Comment: I fixed the typo. Anyway I didn't understand the logic in passing a global instance in the definition of the library, the instance should be this which raises *was not captured for this lambda function*

Comment: @Frank You only have one `StepperDriverController` instance in your program, correct? If yes, then use a global pointer to it, or add a static member function to `StepperDriverController` that returns a pointer to that single instance and use that inside the lambda.